# Angularjs access controller object property from unit test file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following problem : 
i can't access the property text of the object *textes* in the controller from the angularjs unit test file :

```
$scope.ocr = function(source) {

    initialiseZones();

    $http.post("/oceriser", {
        sourceImage: source
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.textes = {
            source: source,
            editor: $scope.addEditor(angular.fromJson(data)),
            text: angular.fromJson(data)
        };


        $scope.currentImage.source = "";

        $scope.showEditor = true;

        $scope.msg = "ok";
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.msg = "ko";
    });
}
```

in my test file i do want to test my controller method so i do the following :

```
it('has to return text from image', inject(function($httpBackend) {

     var expected = {text : 'blabla'}; 

     $httpBackend.expectPOST('/oceriser').respond(expected);

     $scope.ocr('./image.png');

     $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($scope.textes.text).toBe(expected.text); // this line has to be false because the value of $scope.textes.text is different from expected.text value. 
        expect($scope.textes.source).toBe('./image.png');// this line is true and when the parameter of the matcher is changed it becomes false

}));
```

the problem is that the value that i access ($scope.textes.source is correct ./image.png) but the value $scope.textes.text is not correct and is the same one as expected.text

i don't know what can be the problem any ideas ? SUGGESTIONS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `$scope.$digest()` just after the `$httpBackend.flush();`:

```
it('has to return text from image', inject(function($httpBackend) {
     var expected = {text : 'blabla'}; 
     $httpBackend.expectPOST('/oceriser').respond(expected);
     $scope.ocr('./image.png');
     $httpBackend.flush();
     $scope.$digest(); //here
     expect($scope.textes.text).toBe(expected.text); // this line has to be false because the value of $scope.textes.text is different from expected.text value. 
     expect($scope.textes.source).toBe('./image.png');// this line is true and when the parameter of the matcher is changed it becomes false
}));
```

This, in order to trigger the `$scope` synchronization after the http call.
=> Manual in test, automatic in production running.

Comment: @user3099273 just after the flush

Comment: i think this does'nt work because i have this error : 

TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property at workFn

Comment: yep the exact same one !!

Comment: Ok, it reminds me a bug with PhantomJS,  could you configure your Karma  to use Chrome instead of PhantomJS and test again?

Comment: 'use strict';

describe('Controller:ImagesCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('cnedApp'));
    var $scope, controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,$rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('ImagesCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }));

Comment: it('has to return text from image', inject(function($httpBackend) {
     var expected = {text : 'blabla'}; 
     $httpBackend.expectPOST('/oceriser').respond(expected);
     $scope.oceriser('./image.png');
     $httpBackend.flush();
     $scope.$digest(); 
     expect($scope.textes.text).toBe(expected.text);
     expect($scope.textes.source).toBe('./image.png');
}));

Comment: ok this gave me : Expected { text : 'blabla' } to be 'blabla'.
 Error: Expected { text : 'blabla' } to be 'blabla'.
Chromium 31.0.1650 (Ubuntu): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.3 secs / 0.033 secs)

Comment: @user3099273 Normal, since you compare a Json value (object) to a simple string. Change your line to: `expect($scope.textes.text).toBe(expected);`and your issue will go away :) Concerning PhantomJS bug, it seems to have a patch since few days. You may check for it.

Comment: yes i understand that issue, but the problem is that $scope.textes.text has not to be the same as expected.text this is why you told me to use $scope.$digest i think !

Comment: You compare: { text : 'blabla' } to be 'blabla'.  Nothing to do with $scope.$digest() in this case. It's like comparing int and string .. Either you compare: the expected object vs the actual object  or the expected text vs the actual text

Comment: you know the function oceriser(imagepath) returns text from and image , but the text value ($scope.textes.text) is not the same as expected value, and during the test , karma tells me that they have the exact same value ... this is why i think the $digest stuff has to be improved don't you think ?

Comment: yes your are totally right i understand you i use this code : it('has to return text from image', inject(function($httpBackend) {
     var expected = {text : 'blabla'}; 
     $httpBackend.expectPOST('/oceriser').respond(expected);
     $scope.oceriser('./image.png');
     $httpBackend.flush();
     $scope.$digest(); 
     expect($scope.textes.text).toBe(expected);
     expect($scope.textes.source).toBe('./image.png');
}));

Comment: Yes, the next time, could you use https://gist.github.com in order to post your code, would be less ugly ;)

Comment: but $scope.textes.text has to be another value not the same as the expected one , but unfortunately karma runs test succesfully , so the problem is in $scope.textes.text value. it is the same value as expected (variable).
but when i test the $scope.textes.source variable , it is ok for it

Comment: You have to inspect the : `angular.fromJson(data)`, it is at the origin ;)